# mongoose.connection.close() showing error if using below collection.find() method whereas working fine when used inside collection.find()

Tags: mongoose

I am new to mongoose, in my code I have simply created a fruit schema and inserted some document in it after that I simply ran **mongoose.find()** function to read the elements inside console, everything worked fine but when I used **mongoose.connection.close()** function at the end it's showing error whereas when the same **mongoose.connection.close()** used inside find() function it worked fine don't know why?
here is my code which showing error:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.pluralize(null);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useUnifiedTopology: true,   useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 10
    },
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "black",
    rating: 7,
    // review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
});

fruit.save();

Fruit.find(function(err, elements){
   elements.forEach(function(e,i){
        console.log(e.name, i);
     });
});

mongoose.connection.close();
```

**showing error in console cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

but when I used close() function inside find() function it worked fine without any error
as shown below

```
Fruit.find(function(err, elements){
    mongoose.connection.close();
    elements.forEach(function(e,i){
        console.log(e.name, i);
    });
});
```

Don't know what's wrong here, can someone please help to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of async call. Close is called before the find callback is called

Comment: @RobertoBressani can you please elaborate it and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

```js
let elements = await Fruit.find();

elements.forEach(function(e,i){
        console.log(e.name, i);
     });

mongoose.connection.close();
```

You should use `await` also in the other `mongoose` function calls, such as `save`, to have a correct synchronization

Comment: Thanks bro I got it but await was working only when I was putting the save() and find() function in asynchronous function, means without using asynchronous function(async) it's showing error so is it necessary to use asynchronous function when using await

Comment: Yes, sure. Instead, you can use Promise syntax: Fruit.find().then(elements => {elements.forEach(...);  mongoose.connection.close()})

Comment: Thanks bro I got it :)